# Directory traversal attacks

Tags: security, directory-traversal

I'm trying to understand directory traversal attacks from http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/directory-traversal/

I've understood the Attack via Web Application Code:-

e.g. http://test.webarticles.com/show.asp?view=../../../../../Windows/system.ini

where ../ will move one directory up.

In directory traversal attacks via Web Server, it says that web server escape codes are used to execute commands.

e.g. http://server.com/scripts/..%5c../Windows/System32/cmd.exe?/c+dir+c:\

where %5c is the escape code for '\'.

How is this URL parsed by the webserver? To be more clear, once the webserver receives this URL, it will navigate to the scripts folder but then it will encounter the escape code. So it will treat all following characters as normal. So ../Windows/System32/cmd.exe?/c+dir+C:\ is treated as normal. Then, what is the use of .. before %5c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server is set up to block `../` but fails to block directory traversals using `..\`, you could bypass sanitation. You might have to replace more slashes, or a different combination; I would certainly try `..%5C..%5C` before `..%5C../`.

Comment: In windows, backslashes are used to specify a filepath. So to execute cmd.exe, the path would be something like C:\Windows\cmd.exe. However, in URL's forward slashes are used e.g. http://server.com/scripts.html.

What i don't understand is how forward slashes in URL map to back slashes in windows.

I get that we require trial and error to reach the root directory, but i'm confused with the usage of escape code along with the cmd path.

Comment: Forward slashes are tolerated and accepted on Windows just as well; if you pass `c:/windows/cmd.exe` to (the local equivalent of) `exec()` it should Just Work. The percent escape is necessary because bare backslashes are not allowed in URLs. It's not so important that the sanitation happens before percent decoding; the core vulnerability - if it is present - is that sanitation fails to sanitize directory traversal using the native directory separator.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, ../Windows/cmd.exe will mean the same as ..\Windows\cmd.exe to CGI? I understand the sanitization bypass mechanism, but i didn't understand the usage of escape character. To explain my thought, i see the second URL as http://server.com/scripts/..\../Windows/System32/cmd.exe?/c+dir+c:\
(ignore sanitization for now, let's say the server does not check for ../ or ..\ ), then how is "..\../Windows/System32/cmd.exe?/c+dir+c:\" valid? i.e. how are we using the escape character to navigate upwards in the directory tree?

Comment: That's basically the same as http://server.com/scripts/../../Windows/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir+c:\, it just uses a different directory separator. The term "escape character" is IMHO misleading in this context, the use of the URL escaping mechanism is of secondary importance here.

Comment: Thanks a lot triplee. I've accepted your answer. Can you point me to a reference that differentiates between web server escape characters and directory separators?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't; I don't think "server escape characters" is a well-defined term anyway; but I would interpret it as something specific to the server, rather than part of the protocol.